# JSON.parse error on server but not on localhost

Tags: json, angular, rest, syntax-error

I have an Angular8 frontend that retrieves a JSON response from a REST api.

When I run it on localhost everything works fine, but if I run it from a remote server I get a JSON.parse error.
In particular, the error is:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Now.. I know that this error usually indicates that I'm trying to parse an object, but in this case I don't have a single JSON.parse call in the whole project.

The API response is a valid JSON as confirmed by jsonlint.com (and by my localhost being able to process it).

The only difference I see is that on server the error is triggered by main-es2015....js while on localhost this file is loaded as simply main.js and doesn't trigger any errors.

I'm fairly new to Angular development, so I have no idea on how to further debug this.

Comment: Can you get it to log the stringified version to the console and see what it spits out?

Comment: It my be a CORS issue...

Comment: @WillAlexander I'm not really sure on how to do it, since I don't know what it is trying to parse. I don't have any call to JSON.parse in my code, but main-es2015 does..

Comment: @MukulSharma CORS issues usually gave me more meaningful errors

Comment: As far as I know, the Angular HttpClient uses JSON.parse under the hood to parse server responses.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when grabbing json objects from local storage. Are you setting some initial values from local storage that are JSON objects perhaps stringified? It might be that the value is missing in your local storage on the server but not locally or you have accidently not stringified the object at some point in the past and now cannot parse the values out of it.